# How to make auto data update in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to update view when new data created at server? 
How to do this correct?

**My controller**

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'games', function($scope, games) {
games.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0]);
    $scope.games = data[0];
}); 
}]);
```

**My factory**

```
app.factory('games', ['$http', function($http) {


return $http.get('./game')
     .success(function(data) {
       return data;
     })
     .error(function(data) {
       return data;
     });
}]);
```

Comment: Might want to look into web socket if the back end need to be able to notify the front end without being queried like in a normal RESTful request.

Comment: Web Sockets is the answer! http://socket.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that services in Angular are objects. So create a simple method that returns a promise, to manage it in the controller.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'games', function($scope, games) {

        games.get().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data[0]);
            $scope.games = data[0];
        });

    }]);
```

**Service**

```
app.service('games', ['$http', function($http) {

    this.get = function() {
        return $http.get('./game');
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Provider 'games' must return a value from $get factory method.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I forgot to change 'factory' to 'service'. Let me know if it works!

Comment: I have changed the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$timeout` if you do not wish to use websockets

```
$timeout(function(){
  games.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0]);
    $scope.games = data[0];
 }); 
},1000);
```

**Update : sorry it should be $interval**

```
$interval(function(){
  games.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0]);
    $scope.games = data[0];
 }); 
},1000);
```

**Update : how to do this using factory**

```
app.factory('games', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getGame: function() {
            return $http.get('./game');
        }
    }
}]);
```

Now in your controller

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'games', function($scope, games) {
    games.getGame().success(function(data) {
        $scope.games = data[0];
    });
}]);
```

Comment: what problem do you came across while using $timeout..?

Comment: Same result, i need to refresh page to see new data.

Comment: i thought you want to change data in realtime nevermind let me put the code of how you do the same thing with factory

Comment: I add $interval to get method in Controller.